# Hola, modelo MVC con distintos frames

Tags: java, mvc, jframe

quiero hacer un proyecto de tratamiento de imágenes con el modelo MVC pero necesito que tome las acciones de distintos botones en distintas ventanas.
Tiene un frame principal donde se aplican todos los filtro, pero varios de ellos necesitan parámetros, para los que necesitaban parámetros decidí, crear frames específicos para  recibir los valos con los que trabajaran cada método, pero agregue un botón en cada frame para que al momento de presionarlo mande la información y pueda trabajar el método con ella.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//Aqui se reciben las acciones del frame principal, pero 
//ya no se como mandar los de las demas ventanas 
String but1= e.getActionCommand();
```

Pero ya no se como recibir los demás frames, para que puedan funcionar los botones.

```
public class ControladorProti implements ActionListener{
private ModeloProti modelo;
private VistaProti vista;
private VistaUmbral vistaa;
private VistaConvo vistaaa;
private VistaDomi vistaaaa;
File archivoImagen;
String umbralUno;
String umbralDos;

public ControladorProti(ModeloProti modelo, VistaProti vista, VistaUmbral vistau, VistaConvo vistac, VistaDomi vistad){
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.vista = vista;
    this.vistaa = vistau;
    this.vistaaa = vistac;
    this.vistaaaa = vistad;
    this.vista.jButton1.addActionListener(this);
    //
    this.vistaaa.jButton1.addActionListener(this);
    
}

ControladorProti(VistaProti vistap, ModeloProti modelop, VistaUmbral vistau, VistaConvo vistac, VistaDomi vistad) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public void ini(){
    vista.setTitle("Proyecto de Introduccion al Tratamiento de Imagenes");
    vista.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

//@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//Aqui se reciben las acciones del frame principal, pero 
    //ya no se como mandar los de las demas ventanas 

//Botones
    String but1= e.getActionCommand();
    if(but1.equals("Abrir")){
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.showOpenDialog(vista);
        archivoImagen=jfc.getSelectedFile();
        ImageIcon ruta= new ImageIcon(archivoImagen.getAbsolutePath());
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(ruta.getImage().getScaledInstance(vista.jLabel6.getWidth(),vista.jLabel6.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        vista.jLabel6.setIcon(icono);
        this.vista.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes gestionar todos los botones sin importar si están en un frame o otro, solo debes indicar específicamente el botón en el `actionPerformed` y dejar como `public` los `jbutton` en tus `frame` para poder acceder a ellos directamente (Esto aplica para cualquier componente que tengas en tus frames como un `JTextField`) y es que la idea de tener un patron MVC es desde un controlador manejar todas las acciones de tus vistas.

```
public class VistaP extends JFrame{

    public JButton btn;
    
    public VistaP() {
        setTitle("Frame 1");
        setSize(600,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         btn= new JButton("Presioname");
         add(btn);
         setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

---

```
public class VistaS extends JFrame{
    
    public JButton btn;
    
    public VistaS() {
        setTitle("Frame 2");
        setSize(600,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         btn= new JButton("Presioname");
         add(btn);
         setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener{
    VistaP v;
    VistaS v2;
    
    public Controlador(VistaP v, VistaS v2) {
        super();
        this.v = v;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v.btn.addActionListener(this);
        this.v2.btn.addActionListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource().equals(v.btn)) {
             System.out.println("Presione el boton del frame 1");
        }
        
        else if (e.getSource().equals(v2.btn)) {
            System.out.println("Presione el boton del frame 2");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main (String args []) {
        VistaP v= new VistaP();
        VistaS v2= new VistaS();
        Controlador c = new Controlador(v,v2);
    }

}
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo que deje arriba tengo dos frame diferentes pero manipulo los eventos de ambos en mi controlador, el resultado:

**Vistas**:
[image: Vistas]

**Consola**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]